# Which accents distinguish "golf" and "gulf"?

Tags: english, phonemes

From Wikipedia's article on the NATO spelling alphabet:

> The IPA form of *Golf* implies it is pronounced *gulf*, which is neither General American English nor British Received Pronunciation.

However, as a fairly-close-to-General American English speaker, *gulf* and *golf* are homophones for me. I've only heard them distinguished in English accents, never American ones.

My question is, then: which dialects of English distinguish these two words? Is it a peculiar merger that's only happened in my narrow dialect, for instance, or is Wikipedia using a different definition of General American?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, in addition the snippet you quote, the Wikipedia article does acknowledge that a lot of the ICAO 2008 IPA convention transcriptions don't match standard English pronunciations: "Several of the pronunciations indicated are slightly modified from their normal English pronunciations: [ˈælfa, ˈbraːˈvo, ˈdeltɑ, ɡʌlf, ˈliːmɑ, ˈɔskɑ, siˈerɑ, ˈtænɡo, ˈuːnifɔrm, ˈviktɑ, ˈjænki]".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s quite common to distinguish the pronunciations of "golf" and "gulf". Historically, they had the different vowels that the spelling would suggest: a “short o” ("lot") sound in golf and a “short u” ("strut") sound in gulf. In American English, the “short o” sound has typically been rounded to the “cloth” vowel when it comes before /l/ followed by another consonant (or followed by the end of a word).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Other_mergers), a general merger of /ʌl/ and /ɔːl/ (“strut” + l and “cloth~thought” + l, as in "hull" and "hall") is known to occur in some accents of American English, but it is not a mandatory feature of “standard” pronunciation and I don’t think it’s very common. I've heard of speakers having the merged vowel be /ɔ/, in which case this could be seen as a kind of rounding change, maybe similar to the one that produced /ɔl/ from what would have otherwise been /ɑl/.

For me, in the specific context of a following voiceless obstruent (which causes the preceding syllable nucleus to become shortened or "clipped"), "strut" + l does sound somewhat confusable with "lot~cloth~thought" + l, but not to the extent that I would say that I have a merger. For context, I have the lot-cloth merger, so phonemically I have /ɑlf/ in "golf" and /ʌlf/ in "gulf". It seems plausible that some speakers with accents similar to mine might have something like "Canadian raising" here that turns former /ɑlf/ into something that sounds more like /ʌlf/, just as /aɪf/ in words like "wife" is turned into [ʌɪf]. There was a post on ELU relatively recently by a speaker who perceived [/ʌ/ rather than /ɑ/ in the word "scarf"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461539/why-do-i-have-a-different-vowel-in-scarf-than-i-have-in-scarves-and-how-com) (but not in "scarves"), which seems similar.

Comment: Interesting! I'd always assumed it was universal, but I suppose this "golf-gulf merger" is just a peculiarity of my dialect then (and I hear it everywhere because my mind doesn't distinguish those phonemes).

Comment: …though I don't think it's specifically before /l/. Off the top of my head, I distinguish "loll" and "lull".

Answer (score 3):

[Their transcriptions](https://www.icao.int/Meetings/anconf12/Document%20Archive/AN10_V2_cons%5B1%5D.pdf) (p. 58) probably do not represent any actual dialect. For example, [ˈælfa] probably isn't an actual pronunciation in North American English. [ˈtʃɑ:li] indicates a non-rhotic dialect (thus excluding General American); the contrast [noˈvembə] vs. [ho:ˈtel] suggests that they are randomly using phonetic notations since there's no difference in the initial vowels. Noting that ICAO is located in Montreal and they transcribe Quebec as [keˈbek], you may suspect an Eastern Canadian substratum.

I can't say that I've ever encountered a speaker of GAE who pronounces the words the same. [Ogden reports](https://books.google.com/books?id=6DVYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT104&lpg=PT104&dq=gulf%20golf%20homophone&source=bl&ots=dNA_BWfzlw&sig=MdUnhGBLfde_BbykusZZsCY_8Ks&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgqLyW9-jfAhVKHDQIHYGHBbg4ChDoATAAegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=gulf%20golf%20homophone&f=false) that they are homophones for some speakers of Melbourne English, and there is [Wiki chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#From_Golf-gulf_merger) that suggests that it's an Australian thing. [This (unnamed) person](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121222074648AAPzCch) claims that they are homophones, so it's a credible claim. According to Cambridge, [golf](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/golf) is pronounced differently from [gulf](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gulf). If you think the words are more like [gɔlf] rather than [gʌlf], I would conjecture that you're from the Midwest (I'm from the West). There is a lowering going on in the Midwest where my [tʊr] "tour" is pronounced [tɔr].